# How can I delete a process in CUDA?

Tags: linux, pytorch, cuda, gpu, out-of-memory

Providing the error here :
`OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.56 GiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 14.75 GiB of which 13.06 MiB is free. Process 2049 has 14.73 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 14.09 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 525.32 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated.`

For this kind of out of memory error scenario, can killing the process solve this issue ?

I tried running the `ps` command but I couldn't see the mentioned process in the list of processes. So I tried running `kill -9 <PID>` but it says that the process is not found

Comment: It seems you're asking two questions in one: First about freeing memory by killing a process, then about your missing process which you can't find. Anyway, yes, killing a process which has allocated GPU global memory will free that memory. I don't know why you can't find your process. Check whether nvidia-smi gives you a different pid.